# Array with two choices get's me only half way

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make this story in which users have two choices. 
Now it works only half way and I just can't figure out why it is not changing the choices on the buttons. 
Basically it works until the second `if` statement.

```
let startOfStory = [
    Story(title: "You see a fork in the road", choice1: "Turn Left", choice2: "Turn Right"),
    Story(title: "You see a tiger", choice1: "Shout for help", choice2: "Play Dead"),
    Story(title: "You find a Treasure Chest", choice1: "Open it", choice2: "Check for Traps"),
]

var storyNumber = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateUI()
}

@IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle

    updateUI()

    if userAnswer == startOfStory[0].choice1 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[1].title
    } else if userAnswer == startOfStory[0].choice2 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[2].title
    }

    if userAnswer == startOfStory[1].choice1 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[0].title
    } else if userAnswer == startOfStory[2].choice1 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[0].title
    }
}

func updateUI() {
    storyLabel.text = startOfStory[storyNumber].title
    choice1Button.setTitle(startOfStory[storyNumber].choice1, for: .normal)
    choice2Button.setTitle(startOfStory[storyNumber].choice2, for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your value of `storyNumber` is stuck on 0, as that is what it is defined as and it is not updated anywhere that I can see.

You should update `storyNumber` after every decision to make sure the story progresses and should also call your `updateUI()` function after your `if` functions:

```
@IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle

    if userAnswer == startOfStory[0].choice1 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[1].title
        storyNumber = 1
    } else if userAnswer == startOfStory[0].choice2 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[2].title
        storyNumber = 2
    }

    if userAnswer == startOfStory[1].choice1 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[0].title
        storyNumber = 0
    } else if userAnswer == startOfStory[2].choice1 {
        storyLabel.text = startOfStory[0].title
        storyNumber = 0
    }

    updateUI()
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did it on purpose to get back to the start just to check if this code works. As you can see there is nowhere to go further with the storyline. This is why I choose choice 1 for the second storyline.

But the problem is that it doesn't change the buttons on the screen after user pressed for example choice 1 after first story

Comment: No problem - I've updated the answer. Let me know if that isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry but there is no need to write storyNumbber = 1 because it is already tapped in that story if you look at it storyLabel.text = startOfStory[1].title gives me this already. Sorry I don't know how to mark it up in the comment so it will look like a code. the problem is that the buttons doesn't change on another story. I updated my problem as I wrote it in wrong way

Comment: storyLabel.text = startOfStory[1].title updates the label to the new story, correct. However it doesn't update the variable storyNumber. Your buttons are dependent on the variable storyNumber, not the title of the label. Therefore, to update your buttons you need to update the storyNumber. You should also call your updateUI() function after your if functions. Let me know if you've tried updating storyNumber as suggested and it still doesn't work though.

Comment: Yes I did but unfortunately it didn't change the buttons :/

Comment: Have you tried doing that and calling your updateUI() function after your if functions?

Comment: Thanks for help I deleted my previous comment as you also pointed it out so thanks :)

Comment: No problem - happy to help!